# Highlight nbsp \xA0 in vim

Tags: vim, whitespace

I have some patterns in my vimrc to match weird characters in files such as tabs, curly quotes, em-dashes, etc.

```
" Highlight various difficult-to-see problems
:match Error / \t/
:match Error /–/
...
```

How can I add ASCII non-breaking space `\xA0` to this list?

I encountered one of these nbsps in a file when I was doing some diffs, I'm not sure how it got in there, but I had to use a hex editor to see what was going on.

Similarly, in the image, you can see that this turns up as what is, and isn't a space.

[image: nbsp affecting highlights]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `:help character-classes`:

```
:match Error /\%xA0/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the help command too.  Sometimes I forget it's there, but it's certainly well worth reading.

Comment: I would say it's the most important thing to learn.